# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) on devise upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Trying to upgrade from Rails 4.1 to rails 4.2 and in the process devise from 3.0 to 3.4 (due to dependencies of 3.0)

I have a very basic controller:

```
class BasicController < ActionController::Base
  #purposely not inherited from Application Controller to try and isolate the issue

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

end
```

routes.rb contains:

```
get 'basic/index'
```

And my spec for this controller is:

```
#purposely not included spec_helper as I don't want to complicate things.
1.describe BasicController do
2.  it "should be able to get index" do
3.    @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
4.    @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
5.    sign_in :user, @current_user #Also tried sign_in @current_user
6.    get :index
7.    response.should be_success
8.  end 
9.end
```

This spec errors with `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) #./spec/controllers/basic_controller_spec.rb:6`

Using devise 3.4.1 and rails 4.2.0

If I replace factory girl with simple User.create(....) the error still occurs.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `signin :user, @current_user` 
Use

```
sign_in @current_user
```

Comment: I've tried this. Same error. It's not failing at this line, it's failing at the line after.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using Squeel? If so there was an issue in `1.2.2` where Rails 4.2 causes this error. Updating to `1.2.3` fixed this error for me.

Specifically the error was coming out of `create_binds` and they have fixed the implementation, see https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/issues/352

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the turbolinks gem is an answer?

Try upgrading or disabling it. For me this was the cause of error. See: [Why is there a wrong number of arguments error when using redirect_to in Rails 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956998/why-is-there-a-wrong-number-of-arguments-error-when-using-redirect-to-in-rails-4)