# Why is there a wrong number of arguments error when using redirect_to in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In the Rails 4.1.1 version of an app, I have the following create method in articles_controller:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  authorize @article
  if @article.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created article."
    redirect_to edit_article_path(@article)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

However, after updating to Rails 4.2 the following error occurs when the redirect is attempted:

`wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Why does this error occur and how can it be resolved?

Comment: I'm actually running into this after a recent 4.2 upgrade, but am not using turbolinks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Gemfile containing an outdated version of Turbolinks (2.2.2). I resolved the issue by upgrading Turbolinks to version 2.5.3.

In Gemfile:

`gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5.3'`

Comment: Wow. This one was really hard to find, I spent about 2 hours not knowing what to do with this error. Many thanks for that answer.

Comment: I encountered this when I upgraded to 4.2 and all my tests that has assert_redirected_to suddenly fails. I've been at this for roughly 3 hours too, so thanks OP for answering your own question.

Comment: Fortunately, I found this within minutes.